# Troubles with tasks package under TeXlive 2017

Tags: errors, compiling, tasks

I updated texlive 2017 yesterday and suddenly I cannot use the `tasks` package. Just writing `\usepackage{tasks}` made `pdflatex`, `lualatex` and `xelatex` stuck for hours.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tasks}
\begin{document}
Just a test.
\end{document}
```

The last lines on the screen are:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered
.code.tex))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty))
```

After CTRL-C:

```
! Interruption.
\etb@defparser@arg ... #2\noexpand \etb@lst@q@end 
                                                  \noexpand #2&}\long \csdef...
l.147 \DeclareListParser*{\cnltx@map@tokenlist}{}
?
```

The end of the log file is:

```
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
\c@cnltx@tmpa=\count185
\c@cnltx@tmpb=\count186
\c@cnltx@tmpc=\count187
\cnltx@tmpa@length=\skip49
\cnltx@tmpb@length=\skip50
\cnltx@tmpc@length=\skip51

! Interruption.
\etb@defparser@arg ... #2\noexpand \etb@lst@q@end 
                                                  \noexpand #2&}\long \csdef...
l.147 \DeclareListParser*{\cnltx@map@tokenlist}{}

? x
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: This is an `etoolbox` bug in v2.5b and v2.5c: https://github.com/josephwright/etoolbox/issues/20

Comment: Version 2.5e of etoolbox solves the problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved updating etoolbox.